# C++ how to use std::adjacent and std::count_if together, to count the number of occurrences of a condition in a vector

Tags: c++

In C++, I have a class member function that takes a vector of objects.

From each two consecutive objects, I create a std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> (Level1, Level2).

What I would like to do is count the number of times that that the pair for A is greater than B in the vector.

I tried to this this with std::count_if but it does not accept 2 args in the predicate.

So I started t use std::adjacent_find.

How could I extend what I have to actually count the the number of time that the pair for A is greater than B?

```
int mv::class::countOccurances(std::vector<OpListIterator>& sortedops)
{
    std::adjacent_find(sortedops.begin(), sortedops.end(), 

    [](opListIterator a, opListIterator b){
       
        std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> A (a->get<unsigned>("Level1"),a->get<unsigned>("Level2"));
        std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> B (b->get<unsigned>("Level1"),b->get<unsigned>("Level2"));

        return A > B;
        
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are not editing the vector, it would be a good idea to user `const std:vector&`

Comment: Also, what do you *actually* want to do?

Comment: so `OpListIterator` is `std::pait<unsigned, unsigned>`?

Comment: Thanks, I want to iterate over the vector, for every two elements, create the pair and compare the pair. Every time the pair for A is greater than the pair for B, increment a counter. So at the end I know many time there is an occurrence where the pair for N-1 is greater than the pair for N

Comment: This seems like an XY problem

Comment: The pairs A and B will just be (2,5) and (3, 6) for example.

Comment: Hmm... Do you define `>` for `std::pair`s?

Comment: When I call 'a->get<unsigned>("Level1")' it returns an unsigned number. Can't I just use > to compare two pairs of type unsigned, unsigned?

Comment: no you can't. It can be compared in so many diffrent ways. What has higher priority? Do you want to compare same fileds in pair? There is many things to think about. You have to specify it by defining new structure with less operator or create operator for `std::pair`

Comment: I wanted to compare the first then second fields

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. Can you add some examples of input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

ok as i understand here problem is in not defined less operator, so here is sample solution.

```
int mv::class::countOccurances(const std::vector<OpListIterator>& sortedops)
{
    std::count_if(sortedops.begin(), sortedops.end(), 

    [](const opListIterator& a, const opListIterator& b){
       
        std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> A (a->get<unsigned>("Level1"),a->get<unsigned>("Level2"));
        std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> B (b->get<unsigned>("Level1"),b->get<unsigned>("Level2"));

        return ( A.first == B.first ? A.second < B.second : A.first < B.first); 
        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First to simplify, let introduce the projection function:

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> projection(opListIterator it)
{
    return { it->get<unsigned>("Level1"), it->get<unsigned>("Level2")};
}
```

You might abuse of `std::adjacent_find` with that strange predicate:

```
int count = 0;
std::adjacent_find(sortedops.begin(), sortedops.end(), 
                  [&](opListIterator current, opListIterator next) {
        count += projection(current) > projection(next);
        return false; // never considered as equal
    });
return count;
```

A proper way to use would be:

```
int count = 0;
auto it = sortedops.begin();
while (it != sortedops.end()) {
    it = std::adjacent_find(it, sortedops.end(), 
                            [&](opListIterator current, opListIterator next) {
        return projection(current) > projection(next);
    });
    if (it != sortedops.end()) { ++count; ++it; }
}
return count;
```

For `std::count_if`, ranges (ranges-v3 or C++20) might help:

```
auto range = ranges::view::zip(sortedops, sortedops | ranges::view::drop(1)); // current/next pairs
return std::count_if(begin(range), end(range), [](const auto& p){
        return projection(p.first) > projection(p.second);
});
```